# How to make an endless session in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

**The session may end from 10 to 15 minutes on its own, and I want the session to continue as long as the web is open.
I want a simplified way through controller**

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Verify(Users acc, string fullname, string roll)
        {
            DesigenTeemOfMagoubEntities db = new DesigenTeemOfMagoubEntities();
            var f_password = HelperClass.EncryptPassword(acc.Password);
            var data = db.Users.Where(s => s.Username.Equals(acc.Username) && 
            s.Password.Equals(f_password)).ToList();
            count = 0;
            if (data.Count() > 0)
            {
                var category = db.Users.Where(s => s.Username == acc.Username).First();
                acc.FullName = category.FullName.ToString();
                acc.Roll = category.Roll.ToString();
                acc.lang = category.lang.ToString();
                acc.bransh = category.bransh.ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = acc.Username.ToString();
                Session["Password"] = HelperClass.EncryptPassword(acc.Password).ToString();
                Session["FullName"] = acc.FullName.ToString();
                Session["Roll"] = acc.Roll.ToString();
                Session["lang"] = acc.lang.ToString();
                Session["bransh"] = acc.bransh.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("mob", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.error = "Login failed";
                return RedirectToAction("Logincheck");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the timeout of a session as below in web.config. The default value of the session timeout is 20 minutes.

I suggest you to give a big number. The max number that you can mention is `525,600 minutes (1 year)`. Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8) for more details about session timeout

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```